Bounding box is in misplaced
I'm currently engaged in refining Faster RCNN. I annotate my images using makesense.ai. Within these images, I focus solely on a single class. However, upon plotting the images and bounding boxes, I've encountered misplacements.
def plot_images(images, targets):

    max_images = 4
    count_imgs = 0

    for image, target in zip(images, targets):

        if count_imgs == max_images:
            break;

        count_imgs += 1

        # Get the image and the boxes in the right format
        sample = image.permute(1,2,0).cpu().numpy()
        boxes  = target['boxes'].cpu().numpy().astype(np.int32)

        # Define the plot
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 8))

        # Plot the boxes
        for box in boxes:
            cv2.rectangle(sample,
                      (box[0], box[1]),
                      (box[2], box[3]),
                      (1,0,0), 2);

            cv2.putText(sample, 'FIRE',
                      (box[0], box[1]-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 0.8, (1,0,0), 2)

        # Additional
        ax.set_axis_off();
        ax.imshow((sample * 255).astype(np.uint8))

# Train set - images and boxes
images, targets = next(iter(data_loader_train))
plot_images(images, targets)

There is a sample with misplacement of nounding box
Could you help in this context. (I am beginner in this model). How can I fix it?
